# Open or download pdf file for printing from Iphone using JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, extjs, sencha-touch

How can i open or download PDF file on Iphone using JS(Web application).

i am using **window.open(src);** it will work on android & all desktop OS. but not on Iphone.

i generate pdf file from server and want to print that file from cell phone. thats why i need to save pdf file or want to print directly from my web application.

Please HELP.!!
Thanx in advance
:)

Comment: What do you mean by "It will not work", i mean what kind of error does it show ?

Comment: no any error, on mac it works, but not on Iphone.

Comment: also m try **<iframe src="mydoc.pdf" width="100%" height="800px" frameborder="1"></iframe>**
this also but it will gives a warning on ios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a function like following, and pass innerHTML.

openPrintWindow: function (printHtmlStr) {
        var me = this;

`var dt = new Date().getTime();

    var html = '<!DOCTYPE HTML>' +
    '<html>' +
    '<head>' +
    '<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>' +
    '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="appRes/css/print.css?_dc=' + dt + '" media="all" />' +
    '</head>' +
    '<body>' +
    '<div class="print">' + printHtmlStr + '</div>';

    html += '</body>';
    html += '</html>';

    var iframe = this._printIframe;
    if (!this._printIframe) {
        iframe = this._printIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);

        iframe.style.display = 'none';
        iframe.onload = function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                iframe.focus();
                iframe.contentWindow.print();
            }, 1);
        };
    }
    iframe.src = "about:blank";
    var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
    var windowUrl = window.location;    // iframe.contentWindow.location;
    var uniqueName = new Date();
    var windowName = 'Print' + uniqueName.getTime();

    this.testwindow = doc.open(windowUrl, windowName);

    doc.write(html);
    doc.close();

}`